# Is enthalpy relevant to aerodynamics?

Tags: thermodynamics, aerodynamics

Is the consideration of enthalpy relevant in the study of aerodynamics of aircraft wings and yacht sails, i.e. in (dry) air at wind speeds of 0 to 300 kts, in temps of 0 to 25°C in the normal atmosphere below say 10,000 ft?

I have re-connected with thermodynamics over the past two years in an attempt, as a racing yachtsman, to understand the source of the aerodynamic force from a sail.
I have done a lot of reading, including Marchaj, Fossati, Gentry and I have studied Eiffel's research report in his book. I am now three weeks into reading Anderson's "Fundamentals of Aerodynamics" to see if he can provide some answers and have come unstuck at Section 7.2 when for some unexplained reason, he introduces:

"A related quantity is the specific enthalpy, denoted by h and defined as h = e + pv (7.3)"

I have returned to my Physics text (Starling and Woodall) to find enthalpy introduced in Ch 13 "Equations of state" and read that it's involved in the work separating molecules (p284).

Now the aerodynamics of sails is not about state changes: Air is a simple and pretty ideal gas in all stages of sailing (as it also is in domestic flying). No state changes, no molecular attraction to overcome, so I'm confused.

Why is it important? Because I'm trying to understand the "air can be considered incompressible below Mach 0.3" assumption which he "proves" in an incredibly long and complex argument which, inter alia, includes, and thus relies upon, the differentiation of the enthalpy equation at (7.19).

(I have a degree in mathematical physics Birmingham UK 1967, and failed thermodynamics!
)

Comment: Compressing air heats it up, hence there is a thermodynamic loss in addition to the losses to turbulence. I don't think this needs a complicated thermodynamic argument. as long as there is no significant pressure buildup in the flow (which may be true below Mach 0.3), and then we simply don't worry about the thermodynamic losses. The Wikipedia article about enthalpy gives you a different formula which might seem more applicable to you: dH=C_p*dT+V*(1-alpha*T)*dp. Here you can see that heat capacity (C_p) and thermal expansion (alpha) play a role.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "I don't think this needs a complicated thermodynamic argument" please? Do you mean that aerodynamics at the scale I specified does not require consideration of enthalpy? (I don't think it does, but then I failed thermoD!) And I am specifically looking at the relevance of Anderson's formulation of h = e + pV, as that is the one he uses in his argument.

Comment: I simply mean that the heating of a compressed gas (ideal or not) is one of the fundamental observations of thermodynamics. So if the pressure changes inside the flow of an aerodynamic system, which it does, then there has to be some level of temperature change. If it is a small, then we can neglect it, which seems to be the case up to 0.3 Mach according to your source. If it is not small, then the related quantities like heat capacity and expansion coefficient become important. That is where the enthalpy comes in.

Comment: As I said to "neils nielsen" below: it's not the use of thermodynamics that I am questioning, it's the use of enthalpy in those equations.  I am attempting to get your opinion on the inclusion of enthalpy since there is no state change.

Comment: There is not only a state change (the pressure changes), there is even an irreversible process (thermal conduction). Do you mean that there is no phase change?

Comment: A "state change" in thermodynamics means a change between solid liquid or gas.

Comment: As long as the temperature of the air does not change much due to air compression and frictional heating at the surface of the wing or sail, you can treat the flow as isothermal, and you don't need to address enthalpy.

Comment: But the fact is that the temperature of the air does change due to compression, whether that change is large or small is irrelevant to the discussion. If the process (air over a wing or sail) is not exothermic or endothermic and there's no change of state between solid, liquid or gas, why is Anderson introducing enthalpy into the explanation?

Answer (score 2):

For subsonic flow, the pressure changes in a flow field over a wing for example are small and transient and do not involve heat flow between adjacent parcels of the fluid. This means we need not resort to thermodynamic equations of state when describing airflow over a wing or past a sail.

Comment: But the pressure changes are big enough to provide the lift, so while they may be small compared to the atmospheric pressure, they are still very significant and thus will generate temperature changes (PV = nRT). It's not the use of thermodynamics that I am questioning. It's the use of enthalpy that I'm questioning.

Comment: see chet miller's reply.  -nn

Comment: I would like to see your reply, maybe you can improve on it?